# Let X be a topological space and Y ⊂ X. Show that IntY is equal to the set of all points x ∈ X such that some neighborhood of x is a subset of Y .

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Here's what I have:

Let $x\in IntY$. Then $x\in \bigcup_{i\in I} S_{i}$ s.t. that each $S_i$ is an open subset of of $X$ contained in $Y$. This implies $x \in U$ s.t. U = $\bigcup_{i\in I} S_{i}$ where this $U$ is itself an open subset of $X$ contained in $Y$. Thus we have that $x$ belongs to a neighborhood of $x$ which is a subset of $Y$.

I suspect that my execution isn't the best, but does the idea at least work? Feel free to give any tips or corrections.

Comment: That seems fine. You could also choose a specific $S_i$ if you'd like.